# Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages

Tags: laravel, composer-php

I am getting this error while i run composer install 
here's **composer.json**

```
{
"name": "laravel/laravel",
"description": "The Laravel Framework.",
"keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
"license": "MIT",
"type": "project",
"require": {
    "laravel/framework": "4.3.*",
    "illuminate/html": "4.3.*@dev",
    "laracasts/flash": "@dev"
},
"require-dev": {
    "phpunit/phpunit": "~4.0"
},
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "database",
        "tests/TestCase.php"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/"
    },
    "files":[
        "support/helpers.php"
    ]
},
"scripts": {
    "post-install-cmd": [
        "php artisan clear-compiled",
        "php artisan optimize"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
        "php artisan clear-compiled",
        "php artisan optimize"
    ],
    "post-create-project-cmd": [
        "php artisan key:generate"
    ]
},
"config": {
    "preferred-install": "dist"
},
"minimum-stability": "dev"
}
```

Full errors are

```
Problem 1
- The requested package laravel/framework 4.3.* exists as laravel/framework[4.0.x-dev, 4.1.x-dev, 4.2.x-dev, 5.0.30, 5.0.x-dev, 5.1.x-dev, 5.2.41, 5.2.x-dev, 5.3.x-dev, 5.4.x-dev, dev-master, 5.5.x-dev, v4.0.0, v4.0.0-BETA2, v4.0.0-BETA3, v4.0.0-BETA4, v4.0.1, v4.0.10, v4.0.11, v4.0.2, v4.0.3, v4.0.4, v4.0.5, v4.0.6, v4.0.7, v4.0.8, v4.0.9, v4.1.0, v4.1.1, v4.1.10, v4.1.11, v4.1.12, v4.1.13, v4.1.14, v4.1.15, v4.1.16, v4.1.17, v4.1.18, v4.1.19, v4.1.2, v4.1.20, v4.1.21, v4.1.22, v4.1.23, v4.1.24, v4.1.25, v4.1.26, v4.1.27, v4.1.28, v4.1.29, v4.1.3, v4.1.30, v4.1.31, v4.1.4, v4.1.5, v4.1.6, v4.1.7, v4.1.8, v4.1.9, v4.2.0, v4.2.0-BETA1, v4.2.1, v4.2.10, v4.2.11, v4.2.12, v4.2.13, v4.2.14, v4.2.15, v4.2.16, v4.2.17, v4.2.18, v4.2.19, v4.2.2, v4.2.20, v4.2.21, v4.2.22, v4.2.3, v4.2.4, v4.2.5, v4.2.6, v4.2.7, v4.2.8, v4.2.9, v5.0.0, v5.0.1, v5.0.10, v5.0.11, v5.0.12, v5.0.13, v5.0.14, v5.0.15, v5.0.16, v5.0.17, v5.0.18, v5.0.19, v5.0.2, v5.0.20, v5.0.21, v5.0.22, v5.0.23, v5.0.24, v5.0.25, v5.0.26, v5.0.27, v5.0.28, v5.0.29, v5.0.3, v5.0.31, v5.0.32, v5.0.33, v5.0.34, v5.0.35, v5.0.4, v5.0.5, v5.0.6, v5.0.7, v5.0.8, v5.0.9, v5.1.0, v5.1.1, v5.1.10, v5.1.11, v5.1.12, v5.1.13, v5.1.14, v5.1.15, v5.1.16, v5.1.17, v5.1.18, v5.1.19, v5.1.2, v5.1.20, v5.1.21, v5.1.22, v5.1.23, v5.1.24, v5.1.25, v5.1.26, v5.1.27, v5.1.28, v5.1.29, v5.1.3, v5.1.30, v5.1.31, v5.1.32, v5.1.33, v5.1.34, v5.1.35, v5.1.36, v5.1.37, v5.1.38, v5.1.39, v5.1.4, v5.1.40, v5.1.41, v5.1.42, v5.1.43, v5.1.44, v5.1.45, v5.1.5, v5.1.6, v5.1.7, v5.1.8, v5.1.9, v5.2.0, v5.2.0-beta1, v5.2.1, v5.2.10, v5.2.11, v5.2.12, v5.2.13, v5.2.14, v5.2.15, v5.2.16, v5.2.17, v5.2.18, v5.2.19, v5.2.2, v5.2.20, v5.2.21, v5.2.22, v5.2.23, v5.2.24, v5.2.25, v5.2.26, v5.2.27, v5.2.28, v5.2.29, v5.2.3, v5.2.30, v5.2.31, v5.2.32, v5.2.33, v5.2.34, v5.2.35, v5.2.36, v5.2.37, v5.2.38, v5.2.39, v5.2.4, v5.2.40, v5.2.42, v5.2.43, v5.2.44, v5.2.45, v5.2.5, v5.2.6, v5.2.7, v5.2.8, v5.2.9, v5.3.0, v5.3.0-RC1, v5.3.1, v5.3.10, v5.3.11, v5.3.12, v5.3.13, v5.3.14, v5.3.15, v5.3.16, v5.3.17, v5.3.18, v5.3.19, v5.3.2, v5.3.20, v5.3.21, v5.3.22, v5.3.23, v5.3.24, v5.3.25, v5.3.26, v5.3.27, v5.3.28, v5.3.29, v5.3.3, v5.3.30, v5.3.4, v5.3.5, v5.3.6, v5.3.7, v5.3.8, v5.3.9, v5.4.0, v5.4.1, v5.4.2, v5.4.3, v5.4.4, v5.4.5, v5.4.6, v5.4.7] but these are rejected by your constraint.
 Problem 2
- The requested package illuminate/html 4.3.*@dev exists as illuminate/html[4.0.x-dev, 4.1.x-dev, 4.2.x-dev, dev-master, 5.0.x-dev, v4.0.0, v4.0.0-BETA4, v4.0.1, v4.0.10, v4.0.2, v4.0.3, v4.0.4, v4.0.5, v4.0.6, v4.0.7, v4.0.8, v4.0.9, v4.1.0, v4.1.1, v4.1.10, v4.1.11, v4.1.12, v4.1.13, v4.1.14, v4.1.15, v4.1.16, v4.1.17, v4.1.18, v4.1.19, v4.1.2, v4.1.20, v4.1.21, v4.1.22, v4.1.23, v4.1.24, v4.1.25, v4.1.26, v4.1.27, v4.1.28, v4.1.29, v4.1.3, v4.1.30, v4.1.4, v4.1.5, v4.1.6, v4.1.7, v4.1.8, v4.1.9, v4.2.0-BETA1, v4.2.1, v4.2.12, v4.2.16, v4.2.2, v4.2.3, v4.2.4, v4.2.5, v4.2.6, v4.2.7, v4.2.8, v4.2.9, v5.0.0] but these are rejected by your constraint.
```

I need laravel 4.3 setup. 4.3 setup is not available on https://laravel.com so I just get composer.json and place it in a folder and run composer install. Please help how can I solve this problem it will be very helpful for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no any version of Laravel `4.3`. The last version of Laravel 4 is `4.2`.

After that we have `Laravel 5`.

Here is the proof of the versions:

[image: Laravel Versions]

If you want to get Laravel 5 use:

```
"laravel/framework": "5.<version>.*",
```

where:

`<version>` could be any version from `5.0` to `5.7`

or you could use `composer` to create the project:

```
composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel blog "5.3.*"
```

Or if you want to use Laravel 4.2:

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel {directory} 4.2 --prefer-dist
```

Or Change your composer.json to `4.2.*`